# .find() in a populated query MongoDB (mongoose)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I try to make a find request on this kind of model :

```
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface CompanyContract extends Document {
  name: string;
  company: string; // ID of the company
  platform?: string; // ID of the platform 
}
```

And I want to make a request like that :

```
await this.companyContractModel
    .find({
      $or: [
        { name: { $regex: `.*${searchQuery}.*`, $options: 'i' } },
        { 'company.name': { $regex: `.*${searchQuery}.*`, $options: 'i' } },
        { 'platform.name': { $regex: `.*${searchQuery}.*`, $options: 'i' } },
        ],
    })
```

The variable `searchQuery` contains the content of the search (Ex: "Apple Inc.").
My problem is that I don't find how to populate `companyContract` with `company` and `platform` during the query.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by importing the companyModel with `InjectModel()`in the class constructor.

```
export class CompanyContractService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('CompanyContract')
    private readonly companyContractModel: Model<CompanyContract>,
    @InjectModel('Company')
    private readonly companyModel: Model<Company>,
  ) {}
}
```

Then in my search function, I query the companyModel with my search string and stock the response in an array.

```
const companies = await this.companyModel 
 .find({ name: { $regex: `.*${search}.*`, $options: 'i' } })
 .exec();
```

Afterward I declared an array `searchArray` for my `$or` request with the regex name search by default.

```
const searchArray: {}[] = [
 { name: { $regex: `.*${search}.*`, $options: 'i' } },
];
```

Next I loop over the companies array and push the filters into `searchArray`.

```
companies.forEach(company => {
 searchArray.push({
  company: company.id,
 });
});
```

This array will look like this :

```
searchArray = [
{ name: { $regex: `.*${search}.*`, $options: 'i' } },
{ company: 'ff40dea498393'},
{ company: 'df43939498393'},
{ company: 'daa4399394393'},
]
```

And finally, I make a query on `companyContractModel` with my `$or`  filter and I return it.

```
const contracts = await this.companyContractModel
 .find({
  $or: searchArray,
      })   
 .exec();        

return contracts;
```

My whole code :

```
@Injectable()
export class CompanyContractService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('CompanyContract')
    private readonly companyContractModel: Model<CompanyContract>,
    @InjectModel('Company')
    private readonly companyModel: Model<Company>,
  ) {}

async search(search: string): Promise<CompanyContract[]> {
    const companies = await this.companyModel
      .find({ name: { $regex: `.*${search}.*`, $options: 'i' } })
      .exec();

    const searchArray: {}[] = [
      { name: { $regex: `.*${search}.*`, $options: 'i' } },
    ];

    companies.forEach(company => {
      searchArray.push({
        company: company.id,
      });
    });

    const contracts = await this.companyContractModel
      .find({
        $or: searchArray,
      })   
      .exec();        

    return contracts;
  }   
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
await this.companyContractModel
.find({
  $or: [
    { name: { $regex: `.*${searchQuery}.*`, $options: 'i' } },
    { 'company.name': { $regex: `.*${searchQuery}.*`, $options: 'i' } },
    { 'platform.name': { $regex: `.*${searchQuery}.*`, $options: 'i' } },
    ],
}).populate('company')
  .populate('platform')
  .exec();
```

You can do it with this method. It will work.

Comment: No because this code only populate the response not the query, so company.name and platform.name doesn't exist on that case